# Example projects with Prometheus in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, monitoring, prometheus

I want to **monitor my ASP.NET Core MVC application with Prometheus**. Following the instructions on https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net I managed to expose some metrics from my application as desired.

I have no previous experience using Prometheus and I am new to C# and ASP.NET Core MCV in general. Therefore I was interested in studying example projects.

Searching the web I've only managed to find minor code snippets, but nothing close to complete. **Could someone guide me to example projects of this kind?**

Some questions that I am interested in include

- How to expose the `/metric` endpoint? Using a dedicated `MetricController` or simply by adding the `app.UseMetricServer()` in `Startup.cs` as the Github project page suggests?
- Is it best-practice to use a dedicated port for the `/metric` endpoint? If so, how do you expose this port? (`UseMetricServer` does not seem to accept a port)
- What is the best way to add your metrics? E.g. if I want to count the number of calls made to a specific endpoint in my app, should one simply add the count logic in the controller for that particular route? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 6):

I wrote some examples here: https://github.com/PrometheusClientNet/Prometheus.Client.Examples

But, I use my own fork: https://github.com/PrometheusClientNet/Prometheus.Client.

You can adapt for original library or you can use mine.

Your questions:

- Here is your choice. I prefer use Middleware(https://github.com/PrometheusClientNet/Prometheus.Client.AspNetCore) for Web and MetricServer(https://github.com/PrometheusClientNet/Prometheus.Client.MetricServer) for Console
- Best way, use `/metrics` the same port as the application. If this is not possible, then I need details
- You can use my library: https://github.com/PrometheusClientNet/Prometheus.Client.HttpRequestDurations. Or just grab code from my repository.

Comment: Is there any sample implements [Exposition Formats](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats)? (Either in [prometheus-net](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net) or [your repo](https://github.com/PrometheusClientNet/Prometheus.Client))

Comment: In my library, you should implement ICollector. Example: https://github.com/PrometheusClientNet/Prometheus.Client/blob/3.0.1/src/Prometheus.Client/Collectors/ProcessStats/ProcessCollector.cs